# How is the value of this variable being modified here

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, x86

OK, I have this benchmark from SPLASH2 which I am using to test a tool which I have created. The benchmark has the following struct.

```
typedef struct _interact {
    struct _interact *next ;          /* Next entry of the list */
    Element *destination ;            /* Partner of the interaction */
    float   formfactor_out ;          /* Form factor from this patch  */
    float   formfactor_err ;            /* Error of FF */
    float   area_ratio ;          /* Area(this) / Area(dest) */
    float   visibility ;          /* Visibility (0 - 1.0) */
} Interaction ;
```

Looking into the code, I found that **area_ratio** is never used. However, in the end, I see that the value of **area_ratio** is not 0, as it is in the beginning. So I placed a watchpoint on this variable, and surprisingly **gdb** pointed me to a code which modifies **visibility** (the variable just below the **area_ratio**).

Now my question is why is this happening. How come **area_ratio** is modified by modifing **visibility**. What are the possibilties? Any clue? I'm really puzzled. Note that I'm testing my program on a 64-bit machine. Maybe 64 bit has to do something with it, but I don't know!

The code is something like this:

```
/* Create links and finish the job */
inter = get_interaction(process_id) ;
*inter = i12 ;
inter->visibility = VISIBILITY_UNDEF ; // <---- This is what gdb is pointing to
```

Comment: It's conceivable that you've taken a pointer to an `Interaction`, and somehow subtracted `sizeof(float)` bytes from it. That would require what I'll call "pointer trickery" -- e.g. casting to `char*` for the subtraction. So if there's any such trickery with `Interaction` pointers, check it carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I got it! Actually what is happening is that **i12** is a local variable, which is not initialized to 0 and when we perform ***inter = i12;**, the **area_ratio** of **i12** is assigned to ***inter** and since **i12**'s **area_ratio** is random and not necessarily 0, that value of **area_ratio** is assigned to ***inter**.

And by the way, now I've realized that **gdb** shows the line number of the one below the intended line, so its not pointing to the line **inter->visibility = VISIBILITY_UNDEF**, but the line ***inter = i12**;

Comment: GDB doesn't show "line number one below intended". Rather, GDB stops immediately after the instruction which modified the address being watched, i.e. on the next instruction. The next instruction could belong to the same line, the next line, 10 lines later, or 100 lines earlier, depending on the code and how it was built.